# Meaning of "去你的头"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I just heard "去你的头" in a joke, and while it sounds like an approving "go ahead" OR "go with your head/what you think" I realized at the end of the joke it's kind of an equivalent of "go f*** yourself" in English.  Can someone confirm this is what it means. What are some other sayings that are similar to this?

Comment: It is just a way to express disapproval to someone's *stupid* idea. Not really equivalent to the F word.

Comment: In Singlish, the direct translation "your head" is a widely used colloquialism. It means the same thing, roughly on par with 'you dumbass' in American English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not the entire phrase 去你的头... `去你的` alone roughly means f*** you.

Even though you should be learning more useful phrases... here are some more ambiguous favorites:

Numbers:

- 三八(n) san1 ba1: stupid, foolish (typically used to describe a naive, ditsy female
- 二百五 er4 bai3 wu3: stupid, idiot

From stories:

- 猪八戒 zhu ba jie4: fat, pig-like (Pig character from Journey to the West)

Others:

- 冷 leng2: boring, lame... like 冷笑话 = boring joke (lit: cold)
- 臭屁 chou4 pi: arrogant, show off (lit: smelly fart)
- 闪啊 shan3 a: kind of like a  "get outta town..."
- 妈的: ma de: Damnit! (lit: mom's thing)

I'll try to think of more.

Comment: now `你妹` (your sister), `尼玛`(the homophonic form of 你妈, your mother) are popular. The meaning of `verb/adj + 你妹/尼玛` is like `verb + 你的头` and `adj + 个头`. Sometimes, they are written in homophonic characters, e.g. 泥煤, 尼煤, or 尼妹(你妹).

Comment: BTW, I think the impression of 三八 wouldn't be stupid or foolish. Generally `三八婆` describes a woman who is frivolous, reckless, lunatic, womanishly fussy, and fond of saying gossip and listening to gossip and meddling in others' business.

Comment: Very helpful and I am looking forward to more.  In American slang, I would just say to you "right on!"

Comment: also, i know of 吊丝 (diao si) which I would consider something like a "creepy" unlikable nerd or geek.

Comment: @user43633 屌丝/吊丝 is just the opposite of 高帅富(a man who is tall, handsome, and rich). Not exactly mean nerd or geek.

Comment: To me, "去你的" looks like the incomplete form of "去你的头"; neither of these mean anything as strong as 'f*** you' in any context.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @simonmysun's answer "你的头" at the end of a sentence can be used as a gentle rebuke and said with a mocking or sarcastic tone.

Similar to "that's what you think" or "yeah, right!" at the end of an English sentence.

Sometimes my son might ask to eat chocolate right when dinner is served and the English conversation goes something like this:

My son: "I'm just going to eat some chocolate now" (while opening the fridge door)

My wife: "Chocolate, yeah right! Go and wash your hands"

In our house this would be in Chinese and go something like this:

儿子： “我要吃一个巧克力吧！”

妈妈： “巧克力你的头！你快点去洗手。”

You see in this case "你的头" is suitable for use with children and not like telling someone to go f*** themselves.

Answer (score 2):

it's usually used among friends, when A told a joke or B laughed at somebody, you can use "去你的” as a response.

I mean "f*** you" is a little bit strong tongue.

You can take it as " Come on~ " " You are joking " ...

Some similar phrase: **少来了（not serious)**；**你说笑呢（you're joking)** ;
**一边儿去（get away from me)**

---

PS : there is a different context, when argue happens. It means "f**k off"  "get out ".  (Chinese: 滚蛋)

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead!

Here's the joke:

A employee said to his Chinese employer, 'Can I go for a trip?' 'Go ahead!' he responsed. The employee started packing his luggage happily. His colleague reminded:'At the employer's level, his word "go ahead" must means "去个头!"'

23333 (which means, [LOL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/LOL))

P.S. "去个头" and "去你的头" are the same meaning. And "Go a head" is just paraphrased "去" "个" "头".

Actually, the phrase "verb. + 个头" or "verb. + 你的头" itself can be an negative answer to a question. But used when the two know each other very well. Or the one who answers is at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a very similar expression in English "my foot", as in the following conversation:

A: He said he's sorry. B: Sorry my foot. He did it on purpose!

I can imagine an almost literal translation in Cantonese:

A: 佢話對唔住。B:對佢個頭!/對佢條命! 佢根本係故意!

Answer (score 0):

But 你起的头 means “ you started it first”
When arguing
And 走你的头 is “ go, do whatever you want”
Or “ go, use your head “or “ go, do as you wish”

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that it means fuck you.  This phrase and similar ones are most commonly similar to english phrase "my ass".  As in, "You're going to the party my ass!"

So, I don't know the joke, but it is calling  a bluff or disbelief of whatever it is a response to :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Simplified Chinese context, 去你的头 generally means to tell you to f**k off.

Answer (score -1):

i've never heard such a phrase.

as what i know，去你个头 means i will never go，you better deal with it alone。

去你的头，i doubt about that。